# The Crossword from 240BC

Tags: language, crosswords

Use the following clues to solve the crossword:

**Down**
1.  `Loud emotional repetition`
2.  `Commonly a Catholic praise hymn`
3.  `The passel's sentiment`
4.  `Legal court content`

**Across**
3.  [video-games](/questions/tagged/video-games)`A vampire's mispronounced woeful battle cry.`

[image]

Bonus:
Can you tell me the theme?  (It's obvious)

## Hint

> Four of the answers are two-word answers

Comment: How were there Catholic hymns before Jesus was born?

Comment: The clues are not the part from that time period.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Loud emotional repetition

   > Ululation
2. Commonly a Catholic praise hymn

   > Te Deum
3. The passel's sentiment

   > Vox Populi
4. Legal court content

   > In Re

Across

3. A vampire's mispronounced woeful battle cry.

   > Vae Victis - from Legacy of Kain, the phrase was mispronounced in the game

The pattern:

> Latin phrases

Solved, thanks to the fine work of the Puzzling Chat folks. Please take a moment of silence to remember the fine words that perished during the solving of this puzzle...

verbatim

iure

vocative

...they shall be remembered.

Comment: good work so far! we've been working through this in a chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37632/puzzles-etc

Comment: Your 3 across and your 1 down don't intersect correctly.

Comment: If 3 across is correct then I'd go with vox populi for 3 down.