# A Letter: Moriarty is dead

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

I knew the way to his home. I wanted to end this. I was tired of him testing my skills again and again. On the way, I was thinking about [the blood on his sleeve that I saw](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32669/a-letter-when-sherlock-meets-moriarty). I reached there. I opened the door and checked it if there was any auto lock machine like last time. I went inside and saw something that I could not believe.

I saw Moriarty dead, lying on the floor. Shot on his head. Definitely suicide by looking at the scene. How could it be? I checked his pockets, And surely enough I found two letters wrapped in a plastic bag. One of them said:

> Sorry for leaving you alone Sherlock. But I must go. As I am tired of fighting. Don't be worried. The day will still start with the clocks starting from 12'O Clock on its usual way. I hope you will miss me. You can find the reason that compelled me to do so on that game.
>
> -J. Moriarty
>
> PS :- One of your beloved person is in the trunk in the other room. You can open it but you need to enter the reason in there.

I saw the other letter. Well...not really a letter, but a picture

[image]

Why did he kill himself? I wish I had known but as you might have already known that I am not that good in puzzling. So I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Is that a Minesweeper map?

Comment: @mestackoverflow Yes it is minesweeper.

Comment: There is a minesweeper tag ;) (but I don't if it is appropriate so I let you add it if you want)

Comment: @Lordofdark I knew about that tag. But this question isn't really a question about minesweeper. Thanks for the advice though :)

Comment: How to get a free hint 101 : suggest tags !

Comment: It looks to me as if all the numbers in the Minesweeper game are correct, in which case unless there's some steganographic subtlety going on (unlikely given that this is meant to be a printed-out picture) there's no extra information in the Minesweeper grid beyond the locations of the flags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is

> cancer

Explanation

> Take flags to be 0s, numbers to be 1s. Move clockwise starting at the top of each square to get binary encoded ASCII: `01100011 01100001 01101110 01100011 01100101 01110010`

Comment: Damn it. It took me hell lot of more time to make this puzzle than you to solve it. *cries in the corner*